# Get PHP checkbox data from multiple tables

Tags: php, checkbox

First I will tell what I want to achieve, and then I will explain how I was trying to do it.

I have two tables, one stores type of vessels with a description and their own Id. Then I have another table in which the vessel type has been stored as text. My goal is to select each one (both records in both tables) with a checkbox in both and store in the table 2 the Id from the table 1.

I will introduce data, to help.

Table 1

```
 1|Balandra|Some description
 2|Bergantin|Some description
 3|Whatever |Whatever.....
```

Table2

```
Balandra
Bergantin
Whatever
```

Then, I have created a PHP page that shows both tables with the checkbox I mentioned above. Checkboxes store the Table1 Id and Table2 vesseltypename.

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
<thead>
<tr>
<th><em class="fa fa-cog"></em></th>
<th class="hidden-xs">idtiponavio</th>
<th>Tipo de Navío</th>
<th>Descripción</th>
<th>Agrupar</th>
</tr> 
</thead>
<tbody>
       
 <?php foreach ($naviosdyncoop as $key => $navio) { ?>
                  <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                        <a href=<?php echo '../vista/modificar.php?id=' . 
    $navio['idtiponavio'];  ?> class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-
    pencil"></em></a>
                        <a href=<?php echo '../datos/borrar.php?id=' . 
    $navio['idtiponavio'];  ?> class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-
    trash"></em></a>
    </td>
    <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo 
    $navio['idtiponavio']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $navio['tiponavio']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $navio['descripcion']; ?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="agruparid" value=<?
    php echo $navio['idtiponavio']; ?> /></td>
                      
                  </tr>
                <?php } ?>
              
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      
       </div>
       <div class="col-md-6">
<div class="panel-body paneltodo">
          <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><em class="fa fa-cog"></em></th>
                <th>Tipo de Navío</th>
                <th>Agrupar</th>
              </tr> 
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              
                <?php foreach ($naviosforsea as $key => $navio) { ?>
                  <tr>
                      <td align="center">
                        <a href=<?php echo $navio['typevessel']; ?> class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></em></a>
                        </td>
                      <td><?php echo $navio['typevessel']; ?></td>
                      <td><input type="checkbox" name="agruparvessel" value=<?php echo $navio['typevessel']; ?> /></td>
                      
                  </tr>
                <?php } ?>
              
            </tbody>
          </table>
```

So, I want to check both table records and store the table1 Id in the table2 idtypevessel field.
I thought that a PHP file could store both items and call the update function with those parameters, like this:

```
<?php
require './modelo.php';
$idnavio = $_GET['agruparid'];
$vessel = $_GET['agruparvessel'];
```

Any suggestions, because I think I have to do a button to submit this parameters, but it must be working on both tables, and I don't know how to access both `foreach` loop at the same time.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please remove postgres tag

Comment: Done! I thought it could be useful because I'm connecting to a PostgreSQL database, but actually is unnecessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

E. Salas

review bellow reference code to submit multi selected checkbox values
for multi selected checkbox submission **you must use [] operator after name attribute** in html

**index.php**

```
<form action="/checkbox.php" method="post">
    <strong>Cars:</strong><br>
    <?php  
    $cars = array("Volvo", "BMW", "Toyota");
    $colors = array("Red", "Green", "Black");
    foreach($cars as $single){
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="cars[]" value="<?php echo $single; ?>">
        <?php
    }
    <br>
    <strong>colors:</strong><br>
    foreach($colors as $single){
        ?>
        <input type="checkbox" name="colors[]" value="<?php echo $single; ?>">
        <?php
    }
    ?>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

**checkbox.php**

```
<?php
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($_POST);
exit;
```

**In your case:**

```
<form action="/checkbox.php" method="post">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><em class="fa fa-cog"></em></th>
                        <th class="hidden-xs">idtiponavio</th>
                        <th>Tipo de Navío</th>
                        <th>Descripción</th>
                        <th>Agrupar</th>
                    </tr> 
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($naviosdyncoop as $key => $navio) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                            <a href=<?php echo '../vista/modificar.php?id=' . $navio['idtiponavio'];  ?> class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-pencil"></em></a>
                            <a href=<?php echo '../datos/borrar.php?id=' . $navio['idtiponavio'];  ?> class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-trash"></em></a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="hidden-xs"><?php echo $navio['idtiponavio']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $navio['tiponavio']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $navio['descripcion']; ?></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="agruparid[]" value=<?php echo $navio['idtiponavio']; ?> /></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th><em class="fa fa-cog"></em></th>
                        <th>Tipo de Navío</th>
                        <th>Agrupar</th>
                    </tr> 
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($naviosforsea as $key => $navio) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center">
                        <a href=<?php echo $navio['typevessel']; ?> class="btn btn-default"><em class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-left"></em></a>
                        </td>
                        <td><?php echo $navio['typevessel']; ?></td>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" name="agruparvessel[]" value=<?php echo $navio['typevessel']; ?> /></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! But my problem is that I have to store both tables checkboxes, and I don't know how to do it for both `foreach`loops. Because your solution applies only to one of the loops, or am I missing something?

Comment: noworries you can use multiple foreach loop, but make sure you pass array operation after name attribute like **name="cars[]"**

Comment: Thanks! @hirendrasinh-s-rathod, I'm a bit dummie. How do I use the multiple foreach loop? Because I have separate tables in my html, as I stated above, so how do I access both checkboxes from the submit button? Because I need both values at the same time. I actually don't know if you have already answered my question :(

Comment: you wants access check boxes values in php  script or on same page ? review edits of **In your case** block

Comment: I want to store both and send them to a php page that process the values in a function to update table 2. So, if you pick value "Bergantín" from table 1 it stores Id=2 and at the same time you pick value "Bergantín" in table 2 and it stores typevessel=Bergantín. Once those are picked I want to send them through a button like `<div class="boton col-md-2 col-md-offset-10" >
 <a href="" class="btn btn-default">Asignar</a>
</div>` to a php page that calls the update function

Comment: And I'm not using a form, these are two tables.

Comment: if you are not using form and you want to send those checkbox values to php file then you need to use ajax call.

Comment: I Found a solution with Javascript, I posted it below. Thanks for the feedback, it was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this with Javascript. One of my partners helped me, I post this to help people in my situation.
I created a script, here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function cogeNavioDyncoopnet(){
var checkedValueNavioD = null; 
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('checknaviod');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
      if(inputElements[i].checked){
           checkedValueNavioD = inputElements[i].value;
           break;
      }
    }//return checkedValueNavioD;
    var input_nav_dyn = document.getElementById("nav_dyn");
        input_nav_dyn.value = checkedValueNavioD;
}
function cogeNavioForSea(){
var checkedValueNavioFs = null; 
var inputElements = document.getElementsByClassName('checknaviofs');
for(var i=0; inputElements[i]; ++i){
      if(inputElements[i].checked){
           checkedValueNavioFs = inputElements[i].value;
           break;
      }
    }//return checkedValueNavioFs;
    var input_nav_fs = document.getElementById("nav_fs");
        input_nav_fs.value = checkedValueNavioFs;
}
</script>
```

Then I created a Form below, that collects values and sends them to my .php control file.

```
<div class="hidden-xs">
<form class="hidden-xs" method="POST" 
action="../datos/actualizarnavios.php">
    <input id="nav_dyn" type="text" name="idnaviodyncoop">
    <input id="nav_fs" type="text" name="navioforsea" >
    <input id="botonasignar" type="submit" name="enviardatosdynfs">
</form>
</div>
```

I hope this helps. Thanks for the feedback, as always.